# Python3 trying to get access to the object of my class that was instantiated in a thread call

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

Working in Python3, I've created a class that is managing some tables. This class is instantiated in a call with threading.Thread() in which I have a "run" function that is called by the threads mechanism so it will instantiate the class. Now, that function will never exit as it runs some tk code and sits in a endless loop. Therefore the return value of the class instantiation is unavailable.

```
key_gui = threading.Thread(target=key_gui_run, args=(key_name_list, list, sendQueue, ))
key_gui.start()
```

the called function is just simply:

```
 def key_gui_run(large_list, small_list, queue):
   myObject = MyClass(large_list, small_list,  queue)
```

As the system runs the object made from MyClass manipulates some data. I would like to just call a method in that object to get that data. However, the requirements of the thread class does not allow me to get a reference to the object. This is because key_gui_run() never exits and the value of myObject is never available.

Is there a standard way around this dilemma? Am I missing something about Python classes that I should know? I'm a bit of a novice to the language.

Any answers would be appreciated.

Cheers!!

Comment: When do you want access to the instance of `MyClass`? Do you have the time to wait for the thread to start and make that instance? Or perhaps you could just make the instance before the thread and pass that instance in as the parameter.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Threading is only relevant because it lets *something* run while `key_gui_run` is stuck in its infinite loop. You don't have access to `myObject` because it's a local variable. If the only place to create the object is inside a function that won't exit, you'll need to use a global variable to expose the reference.

Comment: I am currently waiting on it to start as I have other threads going ahead, a few watching various UNIX sockets for instance.

Comment: Chepner: I did indeed tried to use a global variable and I ran into type issues. That of course, would be ideal for my situation but I got no where trying to find out why I was getting type errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't you do this instead?

```py
myObject = MyClass(name_list, list, sendQueue)
key_gui = threading.Thread(target=key_gui_run, args=(myObject,))
key_gui.start()
    # myObject is accessible from here.
    ...

def key_gui_run(myObject):
    # and also, from here.
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I definitely solved my problem. I was hung up on the tk/tkinter standard of running pretty much the whole show from inside the __init__() method. I just needed to just use it to intialize some variables and then create a 'run' method in which the big loop is run from. Thanks again!